# Binding (sub)domain to traefik dashboard has 503 error

Tags: docker, traefik, http-status-code-503

Running traefik with docker and bind (sub)domain to dashboard but i got 503 when request to that.

Traefik is modern proxy reverse and i run it with docker by blew code. to see dashboard without direct url i binding port 8080 to 8080 and after that i can see dashboard. in dashboard Route Rule `Host:monitor.monitor.my_domain` was present in front and `http://172.20.0.3:8080` was present in back but when i try to access to `http://monitor.my_domain` i got 503 error

```
docker run -d \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml \
  -v $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.my_domain\
  -l traefik.port=8080 \
  --network web \
  --name traefik \
  traefik:1.7.6-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your `traefik.toml` and overall your question is very difficult to parse. To me it sounds unlikely that without more information anyone is able to help.

If you make sure that `monitor.my_domain` resolves to your traefik instance and then run:

```
docker run -d \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.my_domain\
  -l traefik.port=8080 \
  --name traefik \
  traefik:1.7.6-alpine --api --docker
```

This will work. Navigate in your browser to http://monitor.my_domain (that you made sure to resolve to traefik) and you will see the dashboard.

My advice is to try that first, make sure that it works, and if it does, try to find out what's different with your own setup, by tweaking slightly this example or your own until either this one breaks or yours work.